# Limits involving taylor series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

[Example question using Taylor series with Limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVWVB.png)

How do you go about solving limits like the one shown above? Why is it not correct to express the taylor series in terms of y instead of x, and then multiply the taylor series by $\sqrt{y}$, followed by subtracting y? Like so:

$\sqrt{y^2+y} = (1+\frac{1}{2}y-\frac{1}{8}y^2)\sqrt{y} - y$

Comment: Your expansion is not valid as binomial theorem would require $|y|<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $y$ tends to $+\infty$, $$\sqrt{y^2+y} - y = y \left( \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y}}-1\right) = y \left( \frac{1}{2y} + o \left( \frac{1}{y}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2} + o(1)$$

So the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.